# Add classes (scripts?) to a built java programme and execute their methods during runtime

Tags: java, class, user-interface, interface

I am a student from germany and working on my first own java-project. I am building a small GUI application, where the user is supposed to run statistical tests on historic financial data.
The user should be able to define his own test-methods (in java) by implementing a specific interface.
My idea was to let the **user save his classes (as a .class/.jar ...?) in a prescribed folder, from where he can retrieve them during runtime**. But I have to admit that I have no clue how to implement that ...

My question is, wether this is possible at all, and if yes: Where can I find information on that topic? If it is not, then **how else could I create such an "interface"**, where the user can add his test-methods/scripts after the program has been built?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), although it has its limitations (like no support for generics) it can support very interesting scenarios like [loading a class from Java sourcecode](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Advanced).  It also allows you to define "extensions" either as complete classes or as code blocks or single statements.

If you want static plugins (plugins that don't need to change during 1 run of the hosting application) you could use [jspf](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/) or other Java based plugin based solutions.

Comment: Cool! More than I expected to get. Tank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define custom interface and let user classes implement that interface. This will let you load those classes at runtime and execute method(s) using reflection.

Please check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/